# How do I truncate, create, write, and move around in a file in Perl?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to do these things in Perl?

- truncate a file if already exists, and
- create,and
- write, and
- moving the cursor to end for append

Comment: Why do you have to move the cursor after truncating the file?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `">"` mode for [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

```
# the file is truncated and opened for output, being created if necessary.
open my $fh, '>', "file" or die $!;

# output to the file
print $fh "Line1\n";
print $fh "Line2\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

yes see [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html),

```
seek FILEHANDLE,POSITION,WHENCE
```

Sets FILEHANDLE's position, just like the fseek call of stdio . FILEHANDLE may be an expression whose value gives the name of the filehandle. The values for WHENCE are 0 to set the new position in bytes to POSITION, 1 to set it to the current position plus POSITION, and 2 to set it to EOF plus POSITION (typically negative). For WHENCE you may use the constants SEEK_SET , SEEK_CUR , and SEEK_END (start of the file, current position, end of the file) from the Fcntl module. Returns 1 on success, 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

It's all in [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html). Perl mostly uses the same stuff that C has.

- [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) opens files in various ways.
- [truncate](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html) truncates files.
- [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) moves around in files.